# Iterate over aws s3 bucket and filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got a list of aws bucket objects(images) and I can iterate them like this :

```
S3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects.each do |o| puts o.inspect end
```

So this prints out list of something like :

```
<AWS::S3::S3Object:dss-dev/photos/_097719-10201008011674296-351330164-o.jpg>
```

How can I filter files that contains certain string?

I tried this :

```
S3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects.each do |o| puts o.name end
```

But I got this error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x00000009273798>
```

From the aws API I tried few methods such as name, url

http://amazon.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/AWS/S3/S3Object.html

Is there a way to search particular bucket for partial name if I try to search for `097719` I get this if its only part of that filename :

```
<AWS::S3::S3Object:dss-dev/photos/_097719-10201008011674296-351330164-o.jpg>
```

Or to iterate trough the entire file list and access file name and compare name vs. search string?

Comment: There is no such API it seems.  You will have to iterate through entire list.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'name' attribute on S3Object, you may want to use the 'key' attribute

```
S3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects.select do |s3_object|
    s3_object.key.include? '097719'
end
```

This should give you all S3 Objects with a key that include '097719'

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Also, in S3, folders aren't represented the way they are in normal file systems. You can think of each s3 bucket as a big hashMap where the full path of the file is the key and the value is the contents of the file. Once you are in a bucket (e.g. s3.bucket['my_bucket']), the folder that a file is sitting in is just a key prefix.  So if you wanted to search among the objects in the my_bucket/photos/ folder, you can do:

```
s3.buckets['my_bucket'].objects.with_prefix('photos/').select { |obj| obj.key =~ /097719/}
```

This can GREATLY reduce the number of files you look at.
If you know the file names (object keys in s3 lingo) are going to start with a particular prefix string (e.g. _097719), you can tack that onto the prefix as well:

```
bucket.objects.with_prefix("photos/_097719").select { |obj| 
        obj.key =~ Regexp.new(search_string)}
```

Hopefully this speeds up your search quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in [recent SDK version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html) TravisG's answer above should work had you modified it slightly:

```
bucket.objects(prefix: "photos/_097719").select { |obj| 
        obj.key =~ Regexp.new(search_string)}
```